# Xamarin.Android MvvmCross Data-Binding Issue

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create a simple app that uses the Xamarin Geofence plugin. (https://github.com/domaven/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/Geofence).

I'm using MvvmCross for model binding and the App View is interested in events coming from the Geofence instance.

On My ViewModel i have implemented the `IGeofenceListener` interface so that when any of the events are fired i can directly change the value of the binding properties in my `ViewModel` that are being targeted in the `View`.

```cs
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel, IGeofenceListener
    {

        double _latitude;
        public double Latitude
        {
            get
            {
                return _latitude;
            }
            set
            {
                _latitude = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Latitude);

            }
        }


        double _longitude;
        public double Longitude
        {
            get
            {
                return _longitude;
            }
            set
            {
                _longitude = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Longitude);
            }
        }

        string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
            }
        }

        public void OnAppStarted()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", CrossGeofence.Id, "App started"));
        }

        public void OnError(string error)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}: {2}", CrossGeofence.Id, "Error", error));
        }

        public void OnLocationChanged(GeofenceLocation location)
        {
            Longitude = location.Longitude;
            Latitude = location.Latitude;
            Name = CrossGeofence.Id;

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - Long: {1} || Lat: {2}", CrossGeofence.Id, location.Longitude, location.Latitude));
        }

        public void OnMonitoringStarted(string identifier)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - Monitoring started in region: {1}", CrossGeofence.Id, identifier));
        }

        public void OnMonitoringStopped()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", CrossGeofence.Id, "Monitoring stopped for all regions"));
        }

        public void OnMonitoringStopped(string identifier)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}: {2}", CrossGeofence.Id, "Monitoring stopped in region", identifier));
        }

        public void OnRegionStateChanged(GeofenceResult result)
        {
            Longitude = result.Longitude;
            Latitude = result.Latitude;

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", CrossGeofence.Id, result.ToString()));

        }
    }
```

As you can see, On certain events Im updating the properties of my ViewModel and then calling the `RaisePropertyChanged` event for the `View`.

I've added Debug tracing to ensure that these events are actually being fired.

I can see the events firing in my Output window.. and when i debug the application i can see the properties on the `ViewModel` been updated. It's just that the `RaisePropertyChanged` event in not actually updating the `View`.

Here is my View Code :-

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00007f"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Longitude"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLongitude"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Latitude"
         android:id="@+id/textViewLatitude" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textViewName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the App setup code in my Core Library :-

```cs
public class App : MvxApplication
    {
        public App()
        {
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAppStart>(new MvxAppStart<MainViewModel>());
        }
    }
```

Here is the Main Activity MvxClass :-

```cs
[Activity(Label = "Geofence.Android", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : MvxActivity<MainViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnViewModelSet()
        {

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);


            CrossGeofence.Initialize<MainViewModel>();

            CrossGeofence.Current.StopMonitoring("LHR");

            CrossGeofence.Current.StartMonitoring(new Plugin.Abstractions.GeofenceCircularRegion("Location", 54.9672132, -1.5992939, 2000)
            {
                NotifyOnStay = true,
                NotifyOnEntry = true,
                NotifyOnExit = true,
                ShowNotification = true,
                ShowEntryNotification = false,
                ShowExitNotification = false,
                ShowStayNotification = true,
                NotificationStayMessage = "stay message!",
                NotificationEntryMessage = "entry message!",
                NotificationExitMessage = "exit message!",
                StayedInThresholdDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `CrossGeofence.Initialize<MainViewModel>();` creates a new ViewModel, that is not that one that was created by MvvmCross. You can see that, when you inspect the ViewModel of the activity in the debugger.

**Solution**

Use the `GeofenceListener` property.

```
CrossGeofence.GeofenceListener = (IGeofenceListener)ViewModel;
CrossGeofence.Initialize<MainViewModel>();
```